# LEGO Torsos cracking

Tags: lego-store

I have just recently acquired the new crossbones' hazardous heist, and suprisingly, not even a week went by and my really sweet Black widow figure already has a small crack in her side. Will This damage the whole side? I'm really worried, does anyone else have this problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I would go ahead and contact LEGO customer service and tell them about this. They will want to know as they have high quality standards and this might indicate a defect bigger than just your copy. Also, they are more than likely to offer you a free replacement figure - keep that one safe and disassembled until the one you have is too damaged.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where the crack is. If it is near joints like the legs or arms, then probably you should find a way to seal it. Else other than design purposes it won't harm the figure

Answer (score 0):

From experience the only problem from cracks in the side is that the arm is very loose and the legs don't have a good connection to said torso. Otherwise it is just an unfortunate look.